# Create Zoom effect similar to leanback for ListView

Tags: android, android-animation, leanback

I'm trying to create an effect for my ListView that is similar in looks to what Row items in Leanback do. I've tried looking through `Presenter` and `ListRow` as well as `ObjectAdapter` but haven't been able to define where these animations exist. They don't have to be 1:1 but the screenshot below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

[image: Screenshot]

The "essential" components for this are as follows:

- Needs to animate on item focus to "inflate" or "expand"
- When it's selected, it needs to have a shadow, similar to setting "elevation" for Material objects
- When a new item comes into focus the old item needs to return to its previous state

This does not need to be leanback specific. I'm just looking for a generic version of what the leanback rows already do.

Comment: That's the exact sort of answer I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide some example code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scaling effect is handled by the `ListRowPresenter` in combination with the `FocusHighlightHelper`. The shadow is handled by a wrapper view `ShadowOverlayContainer` which is applied to the items by some other leanback class. If you want to use this in a non Android TV scenario (i.e no Leanback) you'd be better off creating a separate scale+elevation `ValueAnimator` animation on the currently selected list item in your `RecyclerView` or one of it's supporting classes.